# Detect all the rectangles in an image using CNN

Tags: tensorflow, image-processing, machine-learning, computer-vision, conv-neural-network

Given an image of a table I need to detect all the empty cells. I couldn't find any research regarding this online. Is this really a CNN problem? I have tried using some image processing techniques like Hough transform but couldn't acheive the desired results. Any other suggestions on the image processing front?

My CNN approach till now:
I have created a very small dataset using RectLabel labelling software and trained a ssd network using Tensorflow object detection API. The result was as expected with a very low accuracy rate due to the small dataset. I need suggestions on how I can increase the size of my dataset without manually using the RectLabel software.

EDIT :
  [Example input image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Y7CcJ.png)

I need to detect the fillable cells in the table and ignore the ones with text in them

Comment: What exactly do you mean by `empty cells`? And also can you please provide with some example input images and desired output.

Comment: Hmm I would say CNN is a bad choice at first glance. We need some sample images to give you better suggestion.

Comment: @hkchengrex I have editted the question with an input image.

Answer (score 0):

In my opinion, the best way of dealing this is to use traditional computer vision and algorithmic approaches. You can probably do something like this: go through each row and use a hash table to keep track the empty cell (all white pixels) and non-empty cells (not all white pixels). At the end, the result would be the numbers in the hash table. This would take O(n) time and O(m) space, where n is the number of pixels and m is the number of cells.

If you insist on using CNN, then you need to collect many (1000s might be enough) cell-sheet pictures (like the example you have). Then, you should select a network (keep in mind of the speed/accuracy trade off). You train your network like the usual supervised training. Then you can test it on test data.

The learning approach may give false positives so I would recommend the algorithmic approach since it's not too computationally intensive.